# Is it possible to make an Array of Objects in Dart/Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Hello I am wondering if it is possible to make an array of objects in dart/flutter.

```
class Student {
int math;
}

Student[] studentArray = new 
Student[7];
```

studentArray[0] = new Student();

Comment: see `List` class - the docs say: *"An indexable collection of objects with a length."*

Comment: The equivalent of an array in Dart is a `List` created with the constructor that takes a length parameter: `List(len)`. This is not the same as `[]`, the former is non-growable, the latter can grow.

Answer (score 4):

```
void main() {
  List persons = [User("foo"), User("bar")]; //non-empty on create


  List users = []; //blank initially
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    users.add("User $i");
  }

//print using iterator
  for (var u in users) {
    print(u);
  }

  /*
   * first element can be accessed using users[0] or users.first
   * last element can be accessed using users.last
   * */
}

class User {
  String name;
  User(this.name);
}
```

Comment: Thank, I will try this out

Answer (score 1):

Sure thing

```
import 'dart:collection';

class MyClass {
    List<MyObjectClass> myList = [];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To make array of objects in dart we have **List**.
In your scenario to get array of **Student**  type **objects** we define **List** of type **student** and add the objects of student inside the **List**. Below is the sample example code of adding **Student** objects into a **List**.

```
  List<Student > StudentDetails = [new Student (),new Student ()];
```

for more information about how to add objects into **list** refer to the link
https://kodeazy.com/flutter-array-userdefined-class-objects/